# Adding meta title and description to a Next.js project

Tags: next.js, seo, metadata, next.js13

In my Next.js project, I have tens of pages that I code in the `/utils/content/` folder.

[image: content folder]

I include all of the pages one by one in the `content.jsx` file, then I import the `content.jsx` file in the `page.js` file.

```
export const pageContent = {
  ...homeContent,                               // /
  ...aboutContent,                              // /about
  ...whoWeAreContent,                           // /about/who-we-are
  ...usContent,                                 // /about/who-we-are/us
  // all the URLs listed (imported) here
}
```

Here is my folder structure for the app folder.

[image]

And here is my `page.js` file:

```
"use client";
export default function CatchAll() {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const blocks = pageContent?.[pathname];

  return (
    <>
      {!blocks ? (
        notFound()
      ) : (
        <>
          {blocks.map((block, index) => (
            <block.component {...block.componentProps} key={index}>
              {block.content}
            </block.component>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Now, I want to add different meta title and descriptions for each page in my project. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

in pageContent you can do something like that:

```
export const pageContent = {
  "/": {
    content: [...homeContent],  // Content blocks for home page
    meta: {
      title: "Home Page Title",
      description: "Description for the home page."
    }
  },
  "/about": {
    content: [...aboutContent],  // Content blocks for about page
    meta: {
      title: "About Page Title",
      description: "Description for the about page."
    }
  },
  // Other pages with their respective content and metadata
};
```

then update the CatchAll component to retrieve and use the metadata for the current page:

```
"use client";

export default function CatchAll() {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const page = pageContent?.[pathname];

  useEffect(() => {
    if (page && page.meta) {
      document.title = page.meta.title; // Set document title
      // Optionally update other meta tags dynamically here
      // Example: document.querySelector('meta[name="description"]').setAttribute("content", page.meta.description);
    }
  }, [page]);

  const blocks = page?.content;

  return (
    <>
      {!blocks ? (
        notFound()
      ) : (
        <>
          {blocks.map((block, index) => (
            <block.component {...block.componentProps} key={index}>
              {block.content}
            </block.component>
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```